# Incident geometry?

Tags: geometry

Consider the ponits be selected from $\mathbb R^2-\{(0,0)\}$ and the lines in the plane are all Cartesian lines. How can I show that these system of points and lines doesnot define an insiden geomerty? I know that i should show that every pair of distinct points determines at most one line and every line contains at least two distinct points, but don't know what is wrong with points and lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I have understood correctly we need a inconsistency with the points and lines as you defined them. I think if you take two points $$(x_1,y_1),~~~(x_2,y_2)$$ such that $y_1=mx_1,~ y_2=mx_2$, removing the origin doesn't let us to see both of points lying in the line $y=mx$ for some $m$.